# In ES2015, object literals are extended to support setting the prototype at construction

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have read following code on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) side. `_proto_` attribute has comma separated list.

**Does their order matter like anything at first place will be object and the at second place we will define handler and then function and so on ?**

can someone explain the new added `__proto__` added to object literal.

```
var obj = {
    // __proto__
    __proto__: theProtoObj,
    // Shorthand for ‘handler: handler’
    handler,
    // Methods
    toString() {
     // Super calls
     return "d " + super.toString();
    },
    // Computed (dynamic) property names
    [ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42
};
```

Comment: Please note that `__proto__` in object literals was only added for compatibility reasons. You should not use and it might not work outside of browsers. But no, the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

the `__proto__` property point directly to the `prototype` property of `obj`'s constractor. If you run `obj.__proto__ === obj.constructor.prototype` in browser's console, it would return `true`.

So you can use `__proto__` to set prototype for an object. and the order you write it when define a object is **definitly** no matter.

Comment: The first part of your answer seems unrelated to the question.